# How do I print comments of a Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: google-sheets, printing

Can I print the comments of a Google Drive spreadsheet? And if yes, how? I should mention that the print should not be on the same page.

Answer (score 1):

You may not have direct option to print comments from the Google Spreadsheet. But look at this work around and try the steps to take out the comments to print alone:

You need you to download the Google Spreadsheet as `.xls` or `xlsx` file in your local machine.

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd>, this will open Print option page
2. Select "Page Setup" option
3. Go to 'Sheet' tab

[image]

4. Select "At end of the Sheet" option from the 'Comments' dropdown list box and click OK
5. Now, you will be able to see all the 'Comments' moved in to the last pages of the spreadsheet in the "Print Preview" mode.
6. Now, apply the From and To pages to print Comments alone as your print document

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The last update made it possible to print comments in Google Spreadsheet... but that's even a bigger problem.. you can't switch it off. So all the comments are always printed... to paper, when you save as excel, save as pdf. I see no other possibility than to remove all the comments.

[image: an example of printing in GoogleSpreadsheet]